# Jenkins 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no body to invoke'

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, terraform

I am trying to run some terraform commands from jenkins pipeline. But I keep getting  `'java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no body to invoke'`

My JenkinsFile look like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('stage') {
          agent { node { label 'build-java11' } }
            steps {
                dir('./tf')
                echo 'Terraform plan in progess..'
                sh 'curl https://rpm.releases.hashicorp.com/AmazonLinux/hashicorp.repo | tee /etc/yum.repos.d/hashicorp.repo && yum install terraform -y'
                sh 'terraform plan -var-file="/myfile.tfvars"'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by putting blocks `{}` after `dir()` .
Example

```
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('TF') {
          agent { node { label 'build-java11' } }
            steps {
                dir('tf/conf')
                {
                 echo 'Terraform plan in progess..'
                 sh 'curl https://rpm.releases.hashicorp.com/AmazonLinux/hashicorp.repo | tee /etc/yum.repos.d/hashicorp.repo && yum install terraform -y'
                 sh 'terraform plan -var-file="is24-de-box.tfvars"'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```